# Data masking in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, data-masking

How to mask certain inputs before they are outputted in laravel blade? I have created a function in App\helpers.php to mask the email id while outputting it in blade. The character mask will apply based on a specific condition against the user as I have a membership site.

```
function mask_email($email, $masks = 15) {
    $array = explode("@", $email);
    $string_length = strlen($array[0]);
    if ($string_length < $masks)
        $masks = $string_length;
    $result = substr($array[0], 0, -$masks) . str_repeat('x', $masks);
    return $result."@".$array[1];
}
```

Is there any efficient way of doing it rather than what I am doing?

Answer (score 1):

1) **Masking**

So I assume what you are trying to do is replace the every character before the `@` with an `x`?

You could do this with the `Str` helper class

```
$prefix       = Str::before($user->email, '@');
$replacement  = str_repeat('x', strlen($prefix));
$domain       = Str::after($user->email, '@');
$masked_email = $replacement . '@' . $domain;
```

---

2) **Presentation**

A handy package you might find useful is [Laracasts/Presenter](https://github.com/laracasts/Presenter) which acts as a presentation layer for your models.

Taking the `User` model as an example, you could do something like this in a `UserPresenter`

```
namespace App\Presenters;

use Laracasts\Presenter\Presenter;

class UserPresenter extends Presenter
{
    public function maskedEmail()
    {
        $prefix       = Str::before($user->entity->email, '@');
        $replacement  = str_repeat('x', strlen($prefix));
        $domain       = Str::after($user->entity->email, '@');
        $masked_email = $replacement . '@' . $domain;

        return $masked_email ;
    }
}
```

If you are presenting the email of a given user, you would do this in your blade template:

```
{{ $user->present()->maskedEmail }}
```

---

3) **Abstract Presenters**

If you have several presenters using the same methods, you may want to consider making an `AbstractPresenter` like so:

*AbstractPresenter.php*

```
namespace App\Presenters;

use Laracasts\Presenter\Presenter;

abstract class AbstractPresenter extends Presenter
{
    public function maskedEmail()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Presenters;

use App\Presenters\AbstractPresenter;

class AbstractPresenter extends AbstractPresenter
{

}
```

Comment: So with this presenter package if I want to mask another field say phone_number then I would have create another function for the same. Is there any other way where we can create a single function and it works with every field I want? 

Let say I am sending the values in API and I want to send some of the fields in the response as masked. How can I do it? @spholt

Comment: You could either keep the function in your `helpers.php` or create an `AbstractPresenter` with your `maskedEmail()` method which your other presenters can then extend. The solution would depend on the complexity of the project, this may be over the top if your application is fairly simple.

Comment: Application is a membership system. Based on membership some data needs to be hidden. How to do it with AbstractPresenter?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example but it is a little off the original topic. It is just a regular PHP abstract class!